# Am I doing something wrong with this simple #include statement in VS 2022 C++ console app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm attempting to do a small C++ console app to hit Corsair's SDK for some basic testing.  I downloaded the SDK from Corsair's website.  I did these steps and the header file reference  is still not compiling:

1. I created a brand new C++ console app in VS 2022 and it build and ran with "Hello World!".
2. I unzipped the corsair SDK file and placed the header files in `F:\Source\Repos\CorsairEventsTester\CorsairEventsTester\includes` folder.
3. In main.cpp I added at the top `#include <CUESDK.h>` and it complained about not being able to find the source file.
4. I went into my project properties and edited:

   - VC++ Directories
   - C/C++ General > Additional Include Directories

[image: 1]

The error that I'm continuing to get is `E1696 cannot open source file "CUESDK.h"`.  When I follow that link it says to try what I did in step 4.  I am unsure what to try next and this is all that the documentation that Microsoft provides says to do.  At least the stuff that I've found.

Comment: Seems to be a "\dependencies" bit missing in your VS settings?

Comment: Perhaps try `#include "CUESDK.h"` [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/10077)?

Comment: @FredLarson thanks for the suggestion, that produces another error of just `C1083` Cannot open include file: 'CUESDK.h": No such file or directory.

Comment: It was worth a try.

Comment: @AdrianMole I took the macro out and just browsed directly to the folder.  Same result. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Rather, `#include <CUESDK.h>`?

Comment: `F:\Source\Repos\CorsairEventsTester\CorsairEventsTester\dependencies`, or `F:\Source\Repos\CorsairEventsTester\CorsairEventsTester\includes`?

Comment: @Bathsheba I have tried both `#include <CUESDK.h>` and `#include "CUESDK.h"` both syntaxes have had no change.

Comment: @FredLarson I will double check, I may have mistyped that.

Comment: Are you really building win32? The include folder should apply to all configurations and platforms.

Comment: Are you setting your include directories for _all_ configurations and platforms?  This is a common mistake...

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestions I will check.

Comment: Smh @Bathsheba thank you, configuration change to x64 fixed it.  I will accept an answer if you post.  Or maybe just delete this question if it's truly a duplicate and I just didn't know what to look for.

Comment: @akousmata Don't worry about that. Feel free to self-answer and I'll upvote that. (I've just upvoted the question as it's well-asked and sufficiently detailed for it to be answerable.)

Comment: Credit should go where it's due, @Paul Sanders do you want to answer?

Comment: Most folk on this site don't answer for the reputation points, so don't worry too much about "credit".

Comment: Hmm. .. much has changed since my last question I see.  Haha.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments and suggestions to question, I discovered that my configurations in VS 2022 were not correct.  I was building on Windows 11 (x64) using win32 configuration.  Switching the configuration manager to x64 and reapplying the changes to point to the correct `include` directories allowed the build to proceed. I also tested the same thing using `All Configurations` and it worked as well.